# Package does not exist when compiling

Tags: java, linux, import, apache-commons

I´ve made a Java Project on Windows and now I want to use it under Linux. 
Since I am working with Files, I "need" the `org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils` package. Under Windows I am working with IntelliJ, so it manages everything for me. I am sharing the Directory of the Project via VirtualBox shared folder. When I try to compile the Main class I get

> error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
>   import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
>                              ^

I already tried `javac -classpath . Main.java` but I just get the same Error.
To be honest I am completely lost from this Point on, althought I already googled the Problem for a bit. I run Debian and Java JDK 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the Commons IO Jar in the classpath when compiling, for example:

```
javac -cp .:path_to_commons_io_jar Main.java
```